# PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer Alternative

Tags: java, spring

My code is in PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer and it is depreceated .Any alternative.
Code is below -

public void init(Properties properties) {

```
    // SPECIFIC properties (database connection, handlers)
    if (properties != null) {
          ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] { 
                 CONTEXT }, false);
             PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();--Problem 
                                                                                                here
           configurer.setProperties(properties);
      
           context.addBeanFactoryPostProcessor(configurer);
            context.refresh();
           this.DefinitionDao = (DefinitionDao) 
           context.getBean("DefinitionDao");
            this.logger = (Logger) context.getBean("Logger");
    }
```

Comment: Though this is deprecated but this will work seamlessly

Answer (score 1):

If you read [the javadocs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) that tells you what the replacement is.

> **Deprecated**.
> as of 5.2; use `org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` instead which is more flexible through taking advantage of the `Environment` and `PropertySource` mechanisms.

In short use the [`PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html).

Rule of thumb for the next deprecation you encounter, generally the replacement is mentioned in the java docs of the deprecated class.

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
final var configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
configurer.setProperties(properties);
```

Side note:
It even works as a replacement for configuring properties over the XML configuration. See https://github.com/bojanantonovic/spring-properties-demo/blob/master/src/main/resources/my-config.xml.