# Read properties from .properties file present on internet in project's .xml file [NOT in POM file] to update version of module

Tags: xml, spring-boot, maven, maven-plugin, dependency-properties

I have one .properties file present on the **internet/online** (you can say it's an external file). I want to read the properties (versions) from it to update the modules' versions in my .XML file.
I searched about the **PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer**, but it is deprecated. Is there any other way for this?

**Properties file:**

```
github.dd-core=6.5.2
```

**XML file:**

```
<modules>
  <module>
      <name>dd-core-6.5.2</name>
      <artifactid>com.dd-core</artifactid>
      <version>6.5.2</version>
  </module>
</modules>
```

Expected Result: In **version** tag, instead of **6.5.2** I want to use property **github.dd-core** to update the version at runtime/dynamically. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the solutions offered here? [PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer Alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67211000/propertyplaceholderconfigurer-alternative)

Otherwise you can perhaps look into the properties plugin, it claims to do a similar thing: https://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/index.html

> The properties loaded from files or URLs can be used to filter resources differently for different environments. **Those using Spring's PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer** can see how these goals can be useful. Note that the URL format accepts Spring's classpath: style pseudo-URL syntax.

Specifically: https://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/read-project-properties-mojo.html

> The read-project-properties goal reads property files and URLs and stores the properties as project properties. It serves as an alternate to specifying properties in pom.xml. It is especially useful when making properties defined in a runtime resource available at build time.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I used  https://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/read-project-properties-mojo.html and it is working fine for .properties file present within the same directory of .xml file. But for external file, say I have url as - https://abc.technology.com/myrepo/myfolder/1.2.3.4/xyz.properties, then how to specify it in url tag?

Comment: <url>classpath:/config/dev.properties</url ><url>file:///${env.HOME}/mydev.properties</url>

Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: @SagarSikchi besides the `classpath` prefix the input URL is just a standard [java.net.URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html), so any normal HTTP(S) url will work.

Comment: thanks! It worked for me. I forgot to remove the classpath keyword and got errors. But now, it is resolved.

Comment: Also, @slindenau, if you found this question interesting, then please upvote. It will boost my confidence to always learn new things on Stack Overflow :) Thank you.